# Web API2 Help Page Not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an existing `ASP.NET Web API2` project. I thought of adding help page. But my controller methods are displayed only my help page, even I see my page without `css` applied. I can see the documentation `xml file` on my bin folder .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add to project

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
    }
```